# Передача значения счётчика между Activity

Tags: android, передача-данных, счетчики

Есть три Активити, при нажатии на кнопку в первой, в поле текствью выводится значение счётчика "1", также происходит переход на вторую Активити, в которую это значение нужно передать(т.е. во второй активити должна отобразиться "1"), если нажать на кнопку во второй активити, то в третьей активити должна отобразиться двойка и т.д. ... Как это сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Tab1:

```
public class Tab1 extends Activity {

ImageButton button1;    
int count = 0;
TextView t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab1);

 button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button2);
 button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent firstIntent = new Intent(Tab1.this, Tab2.class);
        startActivity(firstIntent);

        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t);
            t.setText("score: " + ++count +"/18");

            finish();
      }
    });

       } }
```

Tab2:

```
 public class Tab1 extends Activity {

 ImageButton button1;    
 int count = 0;
 TextView t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab2);

button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent firstIntent = new Intent(Tab1.this, Tab2.class);
        startActivity(firstIntent);

        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t);
            t.setText("score: " + ++count +"/18");

            finish();
    }
   });

       } }
```

Tab3 выглядит так же.

Answer (score 4):

Между 2 активити  можно передавать некоторые данные с помощью метода intent.putExtra().  
Кое-что можно посмотреть [здесь](http://devcolibri.com/2132) и [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/67-urok-28-extras-peredaem-dannye-s-pomoschju-intent)

В самой первой активити значение счетчика count = 1. При нажатии и выводи. Дальше, это значение передаем во вторую активити:

```
intent.putExtra("COUNT", cout);
```

Во второй активити получаем значение счетчика из предыдущей активити значение:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int count2 = intent.getIntExtra("COUNT");
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, по указанным ссылкам я прочитал всё и даже попробовал,проблема в том,что там описана работа с EditTExt, а не со счётчиком. У меня не получается передавать значение и продолжать счёт в следующей Activity..

Comment: А в чем проблема передать ту самую единицу в следующею активити и при нажатии выводить 2? Твой счетчик - это всего лишь интовая переменная - ее и передавай между активити, делая где нужно инкремент

Comment: Простите мне мою глупость,но не могли бы вы написать строчку с инкрементом, пожалуйста?

Comment: обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

[Урок 28. Extras - передаем данные с помощью Intent](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/67-urok-28-extras-peredaem-dannye-s-pomoschju-intent)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, по указанной ссылке я прочитал всё и даже попробовал,проблема в том,что там описана работа с EditTExt, а не со счётчиком. У меня не получается передавать значение и продолжать счёт в следующей Activity..

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте класс со статической переменной. Решение глупое но все же

Comment: @psyhitus - Решение глупое и очень неудачное. Bad practice.

Comment: Почему же? если надо какой-нибудь большой объект хранить. То делаем Singleton, Registry и храним в нем. Всяко быстрее чем просто брать и передавать указатель на файл какой-нибудь. А в каждой активи его считывать снова и снова.

Comment: Потому что научится человек плохому, а потом кому-то за ним придется убирать.

Comment: Нужно знать все возможности языка, чтобы уметь сделать правильное решение. А вы человека загоняете в рамки! Ещё скажите goto использовать грешно.

Comment: Нормальное решение, только коль скоро мы в Андроиде находимся, то тут есть глобальный контекст - Application. Можно создать клаcc, наследующий Application и хранить данные там. Тут конечно есть подводные камни связанные с закрытием приложения и повторном открытии, но они вполне легко решаемы. Паковать данные в Bundle и передавать в Intent конечно хорошо для мелких и простых объектов, но когда речь идет о чем-то большом вся эта паковка-распаковка бьет по производительности.

Comment: Было бы здорово, показать хотя бы примерный код для новичков:)

Comment: ...ClassWithStaticData.name = mEditText.getText().toString();

Answer (score 1):

Отправь через intent, как и String

```
intent.putExtra("COUNT", cout);
```

Во второй активити получаем значение счетчика из предыдущей активити значение:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int count2 = intent.getIntExtra("COUNT", count2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, `startActivityForResult();` вам чем-то может помочь.

Здесь более подробно, как раз 3 активити: [тык](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/activity.php)

Еще есть вариант использовать `Bundle` - этот тип используется в `intent`, но в свою очередь отдельно `Bundle` может существовать и без `intent`