# Взаимная передача информации между активностями: непонятен принцип работы

Tags: java, android

Здравстуйте, нужна помощь. Есть 2 активности Java. В одной есть лист, который нужно передать во вторую активность. Во второй происходит изменение одного из элементов листа и обратная передача листа в первую активность. Вопрос: как реализовать передачу этого листа в обе стороны?

Comment: А что в этом листе: объекты, строки или ... ?вместо довольно заморочной парселизации/сериализации и передачи через интент, можно использовать простое хранилище, как [библиотека paper](https://github.com/pilgr/Paper). Схема очень простая: в одной активити пишем в хранилище, в другой читаем, что записали, изменяем, что надо и переходим на первую активити, в которой читаем, что изменили и тд. возможно даже стоит подумать о полноценной БД, так как "гонять" туда сюда листы - это детские забавы для обучения, не говоря о том, что после закрытия приложения они будут утрачены и данные пропадут

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача значения счётчика между Activity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299435/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-activity)

Answer (score 2):

https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/68-urok-29-vyzyvaem-activity-i-poluchaem-rezultat-metod-startactivityforresult.html

по такому принципу передаём ваш объект:

```
//при нажатии на элемент списка вынимаем его и передаём в новое активити
intent.putExtra("itemObject", itemObject)
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Потом возвращаете его и обновляете в списке.

Для того что бы передать объект через Intent нужно его сериализовать: [Serializable](https://habr.com/ru/post/60317/) или [Parcelable](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/parcelable.php), в Android правильнее использовать Parcelable он производительнее.