# Android - чтение html файлов

Tags: android, kotlin

В папке assets содержатся html файлы `item_0.html`, `item_1.html` , `item_2.html` и так далее.

В классе `ContentActivity.kt` эти `html` файлы должны читаться и визуализироваться через `content_2_layout.xml`

*ContentActivity.kt:*

```
class ContentActivity:AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.content_2_layout)
 

    val index:Int=0
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/item_$index.html")

}
}
```

То есть считывание происходит через `item_$index.html` по позиции.
Этого не происходит, при нажатии на разные ячейки открывается один и тот же `html` файл, что указан здесь:  `val index:Int=0`, то есть `item_0.html`, а должны открываться разные по позициям

Comment: А в чём именно вопрос? У вас это не работает? Если да, то попробуйте сначала считать текст из файла в строку, а потом отобразить строку в WebView [примерно так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13741394/3212712): `webview.loadData(data, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");`

Comment: Да, вопрос не задал, спасибо за замечание, добавил изменение. Проблема в том, что html файлы должны открываться разные при нажатии на разные ячейки (ячейки и html должны подвязываться по позициям), но открывается только один файл: val index:Int=0 (item_0.html)

Comment: Но у вас же нет нигде кода по открытию других файлов... Наверное, надо какие-то кнопки создать и по клику на них открывать другие файлы

Comment: Подозреваю что проблема состоит в передаче индекса из другой активности: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/299436/11515